# Karma Coverage (Jasmine, Babel, Webpack)

Tags: karma-jasmine, karma-coverage, karma-webpack, karma-babel-preprocessor

After making changes to my karma.conf.js to allow for Karma Coverage, running karma now fails. I'm not really sure what is going on. Any thoughts?

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'], //, 'Firefox', 'Safari'],
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    singleRun: false,
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    concurrency: Infinity, // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    files: [
        'test/**/*Spec.js',
        'src/**/*.js' //ADDED FOR COVERAGE
    ],
    preprocessors: {
        'test/**/*Spec.js' : ['babel', 'webpack', 'sourcemap'],
        'src/**/*.js' : ['babel', 'webpack', 'sourcemap', 'coverage'] //ADDED FOR COVERAGE

    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'], //ADDED FOR COVERAGE
    coverageReporter: { //ADDED FOR COVERAGE
        type : 'html',
        dir : 'coverage/'
    },
    webpack: {
        devtool: 'inline-source-map',
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
            modulesDirectories: [
                'node_modules'
            ]
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
                }
            ]
        },
        externals: {
            'cheerio': 'window',
            'react/addons': true,
            'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': true,
            'react/lib/ReactContext': true
        }
    },
    webpackServer: {
        noInfo: true //don't spam the console when running in karma!
    },

    plugins: [
        "karma-babel-preprocessor",
        "karma-chrome-launcher",
        "karma-webpack",
        "karma-sourcemap-loader",
        "karma-jasmine",
        'karma-coverage'  //ADDED FOR COVERAGE
    ],

    babelPreprocessor: {
        options: {
            presets: [
                "latest",
                "react-app"
            ],
            sourceMap: 'inline',
            plugins: [
                "transform-object-rest-spread"
            ]
        }
    }
})
}
```

I'm getting the following error (and many more similar below this)

> 27 12 2016 06:35:35.997:ERROR [karma]: { Error: no such file or directory
>       at MemoryFileSystem.readFileSync (/Users/lancepoehler/Documents/workspaces/SolarAnalysisClient/node_modules/memory-fs/lib/MemoryFileSystem.js:114:10)
>       at MemoryFileSystem.readFile (/Users/lancepoehler/Documents/workspaces/SolarAnalysisClient/node_modules/memory-fs/lib/MemoryFileSystem.js:297:21)
>       at doRead (/Users/lancepoehler/Documents/workspaces/SolarAnalysisClient/node_modules/karma-webpack/lib/karma-webpack.js:201:29)
>       at Plugin.readFile (/Users/lancepoehler/Documents/workspaces/SolarAnalysisClient/node_modules/karma-webpack/lib/karma-webpack.js:205:5)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
>     code: 'ENOENT',
>     errno: 34,
>     message: 'no such file or directory',
>     path: '/_karma_webpack_/src/components/Error.js' }

Comment: I'm having a similar issue seemingly related to `require.context()` in my test-bundler.js. Did you ever find a solution or a workaround?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be an issue if you upgrade all of these modules